# Отображается пустая страница вместо сайта OpenServer

Tags: openserver

Всем привет. Пару раз работал с OpenServer, раньше такой проблемы не было. Когда открываю сайт - белая страница. Гуглил, ответов не много, мне ни один не подошел. Да, сайт рабочий, на другой машине в другой сети всё ок. С чем может быть связана проблема?

---

Вкладка Network:
http://prntscr.com/dg5yo1

Логи:
http://prntscr.com/dg5zl1

Comment: В логе OpenServer'a ничего нет ?

Comment: Если подставить в директорию сайта чистый шаблонный минимальный пример на нужном языке и он откроется, то в сайте. Если не откроется, то в OpenServer. Дальнейшие действия зависят от этого - исправлять сервер или смотреть исходники сайта.

Comment: Алексей Шиманский - Вкладка Network: http://prntscr.com/dg5yo1

Логи: http://prntscr.com/dg5zl1

Comment: Alex Krass - на другой-то машине он развернулся запросто...

Comment: @ArtemTkachenko, это еще ничего не значит, к примеру: где-то забыли подправить конфиг или не подключили расширение, сайт падает с ошибкой, но из-за включенного подавления ошибок он выводит вместо текста белый экран. И вместо того, что бы сужать круг поиска, мы сейчас будет тыкаться во все что только возможно. А так хоть понятно, куда копать.